# ASP.NET Web Service ONLY returns Documentation Page for all calls

Tags: asp.net

A client has a ASP.NET web service on a shared server (hosted environment). You can go to the web service URL and view the documentation page (xxxxx/service.asmx?WSDL) and see all the methods. Using a tool such as SoapSonar you can execute any of the methods, but the response is always as if you sent (xxxxx/service.asmx) - in other words the web service documentation page.

Is this a medium trust environment? - I don't know, they don't know, don't ask

There are no errors returned or logged. 
This is on a Win2k3 server with 3.5 Framework installed and II6. The webservice was build with Visual Studio 2008 and works locally, just not in this environment.

The client has no access to the server, the third party server provider is trying but of limited experience using ASP.NET web services.

Any thoughts on what could cause this type of behavior? What to look for?

Comment: Part I of the problem is that the web service is under a directory that has forms authentication enabled. So the request to the service.asmx results in a redirect 302. It doesn't happen when you are on the local machine. I tried <location path="//" ><auth users="*" > but that didn't stop the redirect. Is there a way to have forms authentication at the root, but not at the subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that the client web.config contains the following entry:
cookieless="AutoDetect"
which causes a 302 redirect /xxxxx/xxxxxx.asmx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
(hence it appears that the documentation page is always returned).

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the header is sending a POST, rather than GET?

Comment: I can double check that. I did just verify that on the local machine going to the service.asmx and executing the web service (POST) does work as expected, though SoapSonar doesn't even from the local machine.